# how to review specific question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, review

I did get  the question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1139050/planner-graph-and-trilateral 
to review

the question as I did get it:

title : Planner Graph and Trilateral

text:

Suppose G be a Planner Graph with 16 vertex in which that degree of each vertex is 4. when we place this graph on plane as a planner graph, each finite region be a Trilateral or Foursquare, and boundary of infinite region is made up 4 edges. how many Trilateral edge be in such graph?

How we can solve this problem? this is a question on Mid Exam.

tags: 
probability, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science, combinations

There is so much wrong with this question I think:

- The tags probability, discrete-mathematics, computer-science, and  combinations seem irrelevant
- It is an exam question.

The question is I think rewritable to a proper question, but I was wondering would that be the best response in this case?

At the end I just flagged the question for moderators to have a look at it

Did I do this all correct, or what could I have done  better?

Ps I noticed this question already received two upvotes

Answer (score 2):

I assume you saw it in the "First post" queue.

- if you are convinced the tags are not good edit them into something better (I agree they were not good. In addition, there are some issues with the spelling in the question that could also be addressed via an edit; moreover you could add MathJax.).
- if you are convinced the questions is not admissible flag to close it (IMO this is less clear, but you would not be out-of-line either way, though some will disagree).

However, if you are *not sure what to do*, just skip, and let somebody else review the question. Flagging for moderators seems inappropriate in this case as there is nothing to be done that only a moderator could do.

The precise purpose of the queues is to shield moderators from certain type of routine work via channeling it to users that feel capable doing the job. If you are not yet one of these users just leave the task to somebody else. To channel it directly back to the moderators via flags mainly subverts the purpose of the queue.